# 401 Unauthorized for API Response, works on Postman

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

So I'm doing a Get call that gives me a link to make another get call later on. They both work perfectly fine on Postman, but when I try to use RestSharp, I am getting a 401 unauthorized on the second call. I've tried using HTTPClient and HTTPWebRequest but I am getting the same results.

Here's what my code looks like with RestSharp

```
string token = "tokenforbothcalls";
var request = new RestRequest("first/api", Method.Get);
var certfolder = @"C:\folderpath";
var cerFile = Path.Combine(certFolder, "cert.pfx");
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certFile, "pw", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

var clientOptions = new RestClientOptions("https://baseurl.com");
clientOptions.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection();
clientOptions.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

var client = new RestClient(clientOptions);
client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token));
request.AddHeader("Prefer", "respond-async");

var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

So that works perfectly fine, but when I get to the second call, I keep getting a 401.

```
var headers = response.Headers.ToList();
//some more logic to get the link from the first call.

clientOptions = new RestClientOptions("https://baseurl.com");
clientOptions.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection();
clientOptions.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

client = new RestClient(clientOptions);
client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token));

request = new RestRequest("new/api", Method.Get);

response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

Comment: Where are you getting token? Is it the same token for each call? Are two api's calling each other? Your bearer token may be null for the second call and you may have to use a delegate to bridge the two.

Comment: @GHDevOps the token is a string variable that I forgot to add in oops. They are the same for both calls though

Comment: Run Fiddler or Wireshark and see if your request header for the second call is present with the token

Comment: @GHDevOps sorry it took me a while to get back to you. So I tried Fiddler and the tokens are the same for both request headers. I couldn't get much after that because of the certificates. My code is on a console app, do you think I should try looking into Fiddler Core to get more info?

Comment: You may have to write a log file and wrap a try/catch around the code. I'm not familiar with Fiddler Core